# Get website's ID in IIS 6 using the command line

Tags: iis, batch-file, web, iis-6, identifier

I need to get the website's ID by its name in IIS 6 in Windows server 2003. I did it using C# but later discovered that the server doesn't have the .Net framework installed. I just know the name of the website.

```
string directoryEntry = string.Format("IIS://localhost/w3svc");
var w3Svc = new DirectoryEntry(directoryEntry);
foreach (DirectoryEntry de in w3Svc.Children) {
  if (de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer" && de.Properties["ServerComment"][0].ToString() == "MyWebsiteName") {
    Environment.ExitCode = Convert.ToInt32(de.Name);
    return;
  }
}
int id = Process.Start("MyApp.exe");
```

I have to run a batch file to start and stop the website on a remote machine. I am able to run the batch to start and stop the website by using `PSexec` but I don't know how to get the website's ID dynamically. Can anybody please help me with this?

Please let me know if I am not clear enough or if I need to provide more info on this.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like IisApp.vbs is the recomended option. Check out the [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b8721f32-696b-4439-9140-7061933afa4b.mspx?mfr=true) for it. Sorry if this isn't what you  needed.

Comment: it needs website ID.....and I need to find website ID. I am afraid but I was after something else :)

Comment: Maybe I am reading it wrong, but isn't that optional? The plain command will show all the processes in the app pool.

Comment: I just saw your other post, lol. Does that mean that it looks like it is the right way to go? Or are you not quite sure?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking honestly....??Please can you be specific. I will glad to know the right way if you can provide

Comment: In this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857004/start-myapppool-using-iisapp-vbs) you said you were using the iisapp.vbs that I suggested. Does that mean that it does what you need it to do?