# Start MyAppPool using iisapp.vbs

Tags: iis, batch-file, iis-6, application-pool

I have a batch file that uses the following script to recycle `MyAppPool`.

```
cscript.exe %windir%\system32\iisapp.vbs /a MyAppPool /r
```

However when `MyAppPool` is Stopped, then I am not able to recycle it. What I want is to check weather `MyAppPool` is Stopped, if stopped , then Start it, recycle it and then Stop again.

Well I am a complete newbie in this IIS thing and have never worked in it. I am using Window Server 2003 and IIS6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own .vbs script, to lookup the .State of the AppPool, and start it when it's stopped. Something like:

//EDIT:

```
Option Explicit

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    Wscript.Echo "No AppPoolName provided. Iterate through all AppPools"
    iterate_and_start_all_apps()
Else
    Dim AppPoolName
    AppPoolName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
    '
    ' Choose what to do here and uncomment that Sub
    '
    ' start_given_app(AppPoolName)
    ' start_one_app_if_stopped(AppPoolName)
    ' start_recycle_stop_app(AppPoolName)
End If

' This Sub is runs if no argument is passed to the script
Sub iterate_and_start_all_apps()
        Dim objAppPools, objAppPool
        Set objAppPools = GetObject("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools")
        For Each objAppPool in objAppPools
          Set objAppPool = GetObject("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" & objAppPool.Name )
            If objAppPool.AppPoolState <> 2 Then
              Wscript.Echo objAppPool.Name & " is not running."
                  WScript.Echo objAppPool.Name & ", AppPoolState: " & objAppPool.AppPoolState & _
                        ", Win32Error: " & objAppPool.Win32Error & " ("& hex(objAppPool.Win32Error)&")"
                  Wscript.Echo State2Desc(objAppPool.AppPoolState)
                  objAppPool.Start
                  If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    Wscript.Echo objAppPool.Name & " started."
                  End If
                End If
        Next
        Set objAppPool = Nothing
        Set objAppPools = Nothing
End Sub

'
' start an application pool if the .State is stopped
'
Sub start_one_app_if_stopped(applicationpool)
        Dim iisObjectPath : iisObjectPath = ("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" & applicationpool)
        Dim iisObject : Set iisObject = GetObject(iisObjectPath)
                If iisObject.AppPoolState <> 2 Then
                  iisObject.Start
                  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                    WScript.Echo "Error starting: " & ObjectPath
                    WScript.Quit (Err.Number)
                  Else
                    WScript.Echo applicationpool & " started."
                  End If
                End If
        Set iisObject = nothing
        Set iisObjectPath = nothing
End Sub

'
' if an application pool is stopped, start + recycle + stop it
'
Sub start_recycle_stop_app(applicationpool)
        Dim iisObjectPath : iisObjectPath = ("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" & applicationpool)
        Dim iisObject : Set iisObject = GetObject(iisObjectPath)
                If iisObject.AppPoolState <> 2 Then
                  iisObject.Start
                  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                    WScript.Echo "Error starting: " & ObjectPath
                    WScript.Quit (Err.Number)
                  Else
                    WScript.Echo applicationpool & " started."
                 End If

                  iisObject.recycle
                  ' we need to sleep for some time because recyle takes some time
                  wscript.sleep(3000)

                  iisObject.Stop
                End If
        Set iisObject = nothing
        Set iisObjectPath = nothing
End Sub

'
' just issue a start command to start an application pool
'
Sub start_given_app(applicationpool)
        Dim iisObjectPath : iisObjectPath = ("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/" & applicationpool)
        Dim iisObject : Set iisObject = GetObject(iisObjectPath)
                IIsObject.Start
                If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                        WScript.Echo "Error starting: " & ObjectPath
                        WScript.Quit (Err.Number)
                Else
                        WScript.Echo applicationpool & " started."
                End If
        Set iisObject = nothing
        Set iisObjectPath = nothing
End Sub

'
' support function
'
Function State2Desc(nState)
    Select Case nState
    Case 1
        State2Desc = "Starting"
    Case 2
        State2Desc = "Started"
    Case 3
        State2Desc = "Stopping"
    Case 4
        State2Desc = "Stopped"
    Case Else
        State2Desc = "Unknown state"
    End Select
End Function
```

(part taken from http://www.saotn.org/iis-60-start-gestopte-application-pools/, which is a script to start all application pools).

Save as 'startapp.vbs' and run with:

```
cscript.exe /nologo startapp.vbs name_of_appPool
```

if you start it without an argument, then the script will iterate through all applications pools in the the metabase and start them if they're not running.

I think you'll need the "start_one_app_if_stopped" Sub, so uncoment that line (line 13) and run the .vbs script with an command line argument:

```
cscript.exe /nologo startapp.vbs name_of_appPool
```

HTH

Comment: Great answer....+1. Before starting `MyAppPool`, can I check the state of `IIsObject` so that I can start and stop accordingly? This answer is great but I have no knowledge of vb scripting to modify it....

Comment: You can use the .AppPoolState property of iisObject (code example above) to read the state of the pool. Something like: dim appStatus : appStatus = iisObject.AppPoolState.

Comment: Can you please edit your code to reflect my requirement i.e. Start `MyAppPool` if it is stop??